# Shopify read files from the backend

Tags: node.js, graphql, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I am trying to read the files that I have uploaded in shopify backend with the help of this code and [library](https://github.com/MONEI/Shopify-api-node):

```
const shopify = new Shopify({
  shopName: process.env.STORE_NAME,
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
  password: process.env.STORE_PASSWORD,
});
const query = `{
  files {
    edges {
      node {
        alt
      }
    }
  }
}`;
shopify
  .graphql(query)
  .then((files) => console.log(files))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

But I am running into this error

```
Error: Field 'files' doesn't exist on type 'QueryRoot'
 at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  locations: [ { line: 2, column: 7 } ],
  path: [ 'query', 'files' ],
  extensions: { code: 'undefinedField', typeName: 'QueryRoot', fieldName: 'files' },
  response: <ref *1> PassThrough 
}
```

Please if anyone can help me I will really appreciate it.
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE:
You're not using the official Shopify library. The real problem you have is the library you use currently doesn't support Shopify files queries.

You should use [@shopify/shopify-api](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-node-api) to have access to the last updates on APIs direct from Shopify. The rest of my response is based on using the official library to connect with [Shopify graphql file](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-01/interfaces/File)

---

The error msg is wrong.
The trouble with your query is a base rule on all shopify graphql API "you can't ask all elements in one shot using graphql", you should paginate and/or at least declare how many first or last elements you like to receive".

Use this:

```js
{
  files(first:250) {
    edges {
      node {
        alt
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you really really need all, Exist an asynchronous way using the [bulkOperationRunQuery](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2021-10/mutations/bulkOperationRunQuery).

EXTRA: I prefer to formulate my graphql operations on Postman first, the msg errors are clear, I can concentrate on writing good graphql, and when I am happy with the result, I apply it to my code. It helps me a lot to accelerate the development.

Comment: Getting the same error with this as well. I have updated the error in the question.

Comment: seems you're using storefront API, this is the API you like to use or you try to use the admin APIS?

Comment: Isn't this library exposing admin APIs, do you have any idea or how to use admin APIs?

Comment: i use apollo client is the same shopify use on their node app example, if you are on early stages of development i recommend you migrate your project to shopify cli https://shopify.dev/apps/tools/cli  it's easy to start and very flexible to expand with your own code and functionalities.